# Python PyQt dynamic widget generation using multithread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I am writing a simple program that reads new input being written to a file and displays it in popup windows.

I am using PyQt5 for:
A) File changes (QtCore)
B) Window (QtWidgets)

> **Note that I do actually have a working model using signals as per PyQt reference guide. But couldn't figured out the below, therefore I am not understanding how things works.**

While testing implementations i came across with multi-thread issues.
This is a simplified example of my problem:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
import threading

def additem(window):
    """ generates label in window at bottom """
    print("Adding label to window on thread {}".format(threading.currentThread()))
    row = window.layout().rowCount() + 1
    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('button_' + str(row), window)
    window.layout().addWidget(btn,row,1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w.setLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout())
    # set to timers after 3,6 will generate label in window
    threading.Timer(3,additem,args=(w,)).start()
    threading.Timer(6,additem,args=(w,)).start()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

> Adding label to window
>   QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in different thread

I tried setting global queue to pass around objects but still same error.

Although I now why the exception is raised, I do not understand how to avoid it.

One attempt was to directly pass the top object "app" and then getting the window by index (app is the top parent):

```
...
threading.Timer(3,additem,args=(app,)).start()
...

def additem(app):
    w = app.allWidgets()[0]
    ...
```

I know PyQt is a C library wrapped in python but I am not familiar with C. The app object is a pointer to the object in the memory heap,
why it can't manipulate the object?
is the object being copied in a new thread? (thought I could still "update" that object)

Comment: Qt does not support the creation or update of the GUI from another thread, for more information read the following: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Comment: I didn't know how to google that issue. Pretty clear now. The built-in signal methods work as a charm I just wanted to know why does not works otherwise. Many thanks! really helpful and new stuff to learn!